# Wicket: rendering HTML5 audio from plain string

Tags: java, html, wicket, html5-audio

I'd like to render HTML5 audio using Apache Wicket.
I am trying to render it from plain string. I know it's probably not the best way to do this so first I'd like to ask: is it even possible without getting errors?

Here's what I'm doing:

JAVA:

```
String html5AudioStr = "<audio controls><source src=\"test.mp3\" type=\"audio/mpeg\">Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>";
add(new Label("html5Audio", html5AudioStr).setEscapeModelStrings(false));
```

HTML:

```
<span wicket:id="html5Audio"></span>
```

By doing this, I can see the audio player and the `<audio>` tag is rendered correctly. But I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.mp3
```

And the file has this URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/wicket/bookmarkable/test.mp3
```

instead of:

```
http://localhost:8080/test.mp3
```

Is there anything I could do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use relative path for source. That's why browser is trying resolve absolute path relative to your page (seems it's located in /wicket/bookmarkable/).

If you are going to use / context you can simply add "/" before "test.mp3" - it should be "/test.mp3".

But if you are going to mount your application to other place rather then root context "/", I recommend to take a look to 'ContextRelativeResource'.

Answer (score 1):

As of Wicket 7 media tags (audio, video, track, source) are now part of the core API.

**Documentation:**

[Wicket User Guide 7.x - 16.3 Package resources](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/7.x/guide/resources.html#resources_3)

- "Media tags - resource references with content range support"

**Javadoc:**

https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/7.x/index.html - Packages:

- [org.apache.wicket.markup.html.media](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/7.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/media/package-frame.html)
- [org.apache.wicket.markup.html.media.audio](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/7.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/media/audio/package-frame.html)
- [org.apache.wicket.markup.html.media.video](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/7.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/media/video/package-frame.html)

There are also some additional implementations in the "html5" module of WicketStuff about Subtitles and WebRTC.

- https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/wiki/Html5